# Repeating integer if passed variable used beneath two consecutive if statements

Tags: c

I really don't know how to title this but in the following code segment, when I pass a number into `sad()`, it's supposed to change `tmp1` to that number, output the number, then exit. Then on the next iteration in `main()`, `tmp2` in `sad()` is supposed to output that number. `tmp3` will be equal to `10 * tmp1 + tmp2`, this merges the two numbers together. Both of the numbers outputted above are fine, but when it gets to after the second `if` statement, it repeats the numbers. For instance if I made `tmp3 = tmp1`, it would repeat `3` six times. How do you make it not repeat?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char tmp1 = 'a';
char tmp2 = 'a';
char tmp3 = 'a';
char sad(char a)
{       
        //int same as char, char not same as int
        //tmp3 eventually equals tmp1   
        if (tmp1 == 'a') //if number skip
        {
                tmp1 = a;
                printf("tmp1 %d\n", tmp1);
                return 0;
        }
        if (tmp2 == 'a') //if number skip
        {
                tmp2 = a;
                printf("tmp2 %d\n", tmp2);
        }
        tmp3 = 10 * tmp1 + tmp2;
        printf("%d", tmp1); 
        return 0;


}
int main()
{
        int tmpnum[8] = {3, 2, 123, 342, 23, 32, 0, 12};
        int i;  
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(tmpnum) / sizeof(tmpnum[0]); i++)
        {
                sad(tmpnum[i]);
        }       
}
```

Comment: Don't use global variables where local (automatic) variables will do as well. Use a debugger to see step through your code and see the values.

Comment: They won't do becuase everytime the function is called, the value will equal back to 'a', and I can't have that.as I need them to stay the number until further notice.

Comment: I am not sure what your expected output should be. After the first two calls to `sad()`, `tmp1` and `tmp2` have been set to non-`'a'`, so the first two `if`s are skipped, `tmp1` and `tmp2` are never reset, so `tmp3` will always get the same value, _and_ you are printing the value of `tmp1` here. The reported output is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is return in the second if and reset the initial values in the subsequent paragraph:

```
char sad(char a)
{       
    static char tmp1 = 'a';
    static char tmp2 = 'a';
    static char tmp3 = 'a';

    //int same as char, char not same as int
    //tmp3 eventually equals tmp1   
    if (tmp1 == 'a') //if number skip
    {
        tmp1 = a;
        printf("tmp1 %d\n", tmp1);
        return 0;
    }
    if (tmp2 == 'a') //if number skip
    {
        tmp2 = a;
        printf("tmp2 %d\n", tmp2);
        return 0;
    }
    tmp3 = 10 * tmp1 + tmp2;
    printf("%d", tmp3); // this should be tmp3 not tmp1, right?
    tmp1 = 'a';
    tmp2 = 'a';
    return 0;
}
```

You can make the logic more obvious using a state variable separate from the tmp variables.

```
char sad(char a)
{       
    static char tmp1 = 'a';
    static char tmp2 = 'a';
    char tmp3;
    static state=0;

    switch(state)
    {
    case 0:
        tmp1 = a;
        printf("tmp1 %d\n", tmp1);
        state = 1;
        return 0;

    case 1:
        tmp2 = a;
        printf("tmp2 %d\n", tmp2);
        state = 2;
        return 0;

    case 2:
        tmp3 = 10 * tmp1 + tmp2;
        printf("%d", tmp3); // this should be tmp3 not tmp1, right?
        state = 0;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I have a solution. I can just print tmp3 in main rather than in sad. I think it's because the for loop that is calling all the variables is getting to that point and just executing the printing of the tmp3.